# Sorting the C# List with Date(11 Sep 2015 --> Date format) in Descending Order?

Tags: c#, sorting, date

```
indexlist = saveList
    .Where(i => (Convert.ToDateTime(i.event_startdate) < DateTime.Today) 
             && (Convert.ToDateTime(i.event_endDate)   < DateTime.Today))
    .ToList();
Event_list.ItemsSource = indexlist.OrderBy(i => i.event_startdate);
```

I wrote the code like above to sort the List which contains the date in this format(11 Sep 2015), I want to sort it in the way that, it should display Most recent date date on Top of list.
How to Modify the above statement

I have tried using `OrderByDescending(i=>i.event_startdate);` but no use.

Comment: so how did it not work if you've converted it to a true date field it should sort it

Comment: Why do you create the list before you order it?

Comment: You arent changing the date to be a date, its just a string so you would get 1 Jan, 1 Feb, 1 Sep, 2 Jan..

Comment: What is the type of the `saveList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the date to`DateTime` object in order to sort by it, then things would be easy:

```
var results = (from item in saveList
                let dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(item.event_startdate)
                let dtEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(item.event_endDate)
                where dtStart.Date < DateTime.Today && dtEnd.Date < DateTime.Today
                orderby dtStart descending
                select item).ToList();

Event_list.ItemsSource = results;
```

Comment: Iam getting the list as below 24 Mar 2016,18 Nov 2015,11 Sep 2015,14 Aug 2015,22 Jul 2015,16 Apr 2015,14 Nov 2014,23 Aug 2014,16 Aug 2014,3 Mar 2014,6 Mar 2015,7Mar 2015,2 May 2015,6 Sep 2015. This list is half sorted, I want it to be Most Recent Date on top and oldest date at the bottom.

Comment: But my list is like , in the middle dates from 2014 are showing and at the end 2015 dates are showing. Once check the dates i have posted, they started with 24 Mar 2016 went on up to 16 Apr 2015, then to 14 Nov 2014,23 Aug 2014,3 Mar 2014 and then again to 6 Mar 2015,7 Mar 2015 etc..

Comment: It is Working, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You are filtering the items by a converted `DateTime` but you are ordering it by the `string`/`object` which is incorrect. You can store the `DateTime` in an anoymous type:

```
indexlist = saveList
    .Select(i => new { 
        event = i, 
        event_startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(i.event_startdate),
        event_endDate   = Convert.ToDateTime(i.event_endDate),
    })
    .Where(x => x.event_startdate < DateTime.Today && x.event_endDate < DateTime.Today)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.event_startdate)
    .Select(x => x.event)
    .ToList();
Event_list.ItemsSource = indexlist;
```

Comment: Isn't it `OrderByDescending`?